# Unlink permission denied on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions, unlink

How do I delete a file, Below the output of the code.. but this code is not working to del the file from the directory....

**in controller**

```
public function delete_by_id()
{
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $schemeid = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $link = $this->uri->segment(5);

        $tablename = $this->uri->segment(6);
     //unlink code ------------------------------------------>
      $del_image = $this->C_model->getrecordwhere($tablename, array('id' => $id));

      unlink('upload_attachments/'.$del_image->attched_files);


       echo '<pre>';print_r($del_image);die;
   // if($tablename== 'progress')
  //  {

        $where = array('id'=>$id);
        //$where = array('id'=>$id);
        //$where = array('id'=>$id);
        //$where = array('id'=>$id);
        $this->C_model->deleteid($tablename,$where);

        redirect('C2C_contr/'.$link.'/'.$schemeid);

}
```

**output**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/C2C_contr.php
>
> Line Number: 264
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/C2C_contr.php
>
> Line Number: 267
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: unlink(upload_attachments/): Permission denied
>
> Filename: controllers/C2C_contr.php
>
> Line Number: 267
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [id] => 111
>             [attched_files] => Untitled4.png
>             [attched_remarks] => 
>         )
> )
> ```

Comment: Have you loaded this C_model in constructor?

Comment: public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('C_model');
               
    }

I already loaded the Model in constructor

file are delete form the table but not delete form the directory path

Comment: use $del_image[0] inplace of $del_image than try it.

Answer (score 1):

You should update below line -

unlink('upload_attachments/'.$del_image->attched_files);

//update with this

unlink('upload_attachments/'.$del_image[0]['attched_files']);